# How to solve for "k"

Tags: differential-equations

So the question is given that the atmospheric pressure is modelled by the differential equation p'[h]=-kp[h], p[0]=1013, p[20]=50. find k and comstant of integration.

My code was:

```
DE=p'[h]==-k p[h]
DSolve[{DE,p[0]==1013},p[h],h]
```

The output was:

```
p'[h]==-k p[h]
p[h]->1013e^(-kh)
```

Then to solve for k i wrote

```
Solve[p[20]==50,k,Reals]
```

But this is not solving for k.

Can someone point out the mistake and tell me what is the correct way. Thank you

Comment: try `DE = p'[h] == -k p[h];
sol = DSolve[{DE, p[0] == 1013}, p, h][[1]];
k /. Solve[p[20] == 50 /. sol, k, Reals][[1]]`

Comment: @chris what is the meaning of [[1]]?

Comment: you can remove it if you wish: DSolve returns a list of solutions; [[1]] takes the first (which happens to be the only one here).

Comment: oh ok thanks. i'll try it and let u know : )

Comment: @chris in your code the difference is you used /.sol in solve, what has it done that my was not able to output the answer, it carried the same meaning i suppose

Comment: your code returned an expression p[h]; you wanted a function so as to take 20 as an argument. This is the difference between DSolve[{DE, p[0] == 1013}, p, h] and DSolve[{DE, p[0] == 1013}, p[h], h]. DSolve does dot define the function p[h] it returns a rule to define it.

Comment: @chris why would it, i asked to solve for "k". sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: In your code `DSolve` does not do anything to `p[h]`. It does not define `p[h]` as the solution to the differential equation. In programming this is called a side-effect, something that is not common in Mathematica. What `DSolve` does, is return a rule saying "If p[h] is the unknown function, a rule to define it would look like this". You then actually have to take a function and define it using this rule. Further, you still cannot plot it, until you have also given a numeric value to `k`, otherwise the function won't evaluate to a number.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP thanks a lot, understood it clearly. But can u elaborate the plotting part in an answer, giving the plot. chris gave it but it is all too advanced i cant make it it out. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By request of OP

```
DE = p'[h] == -k p[h]; (* Assign an equation to the symbol DE *)
                       (* semicolon omits the output *)
dsol = DSolve[{DE, p[0] == 1013}, p[h], h] (* Assign the rule that is produced
                                              for a p[h], such that it would be
                                              the solution to the equation to the
                                              symbol dsol *)
{{p[h] -> 1013 E^(-h k)}} (* <--- output, which is value of dsol *)
```

Note that `dsol` is a doubly nested list - `{{...}}`. We need one solution, not a list of solutions. Let's take the first (and only) solution:

```
dsol = First[dsol]
(* {p[h] -> 1013 E^(-h k)} *)
```

Ok, this is a proper rule. Let's now define a function, which is compliant to this rule. I'll have to use `ReplaceAll` for that and if you're going to be using Mathematica a lot, you'll need to get familiar with it. It's very common and used all over the place.

```
p1[h_] = p[h] /. dsol
```

Read from left to right this means "let `p1[h_]` where `h_` is a pattern standing for any single (not multiple) argument be equal to `p[h]`, but not just any old `p[h]`, but the `p[h]` you would get if you apply the rule `dsol` which transforms any occurence of `p[h]` to `1013 E^(-h k)`". `/.` could be read as "taking into account that such and such rule applies", it is the shorthand form of `ReplaceAll`.

Having done all that:

```
p1[h]
p1[2]
p1[20]
(* 1013 E^(-h k) *)
(* 1013 E^(-2 k) *)
(* 1013 E^(-20 k) *)
```

`p1[h]` doesn't evaluate to numbers. It's not only a function of `h`, but also depends on a parameter `k`. Unless we tell Mathematica, what must `k` be replaced with (more replacements!), it won't be able to plot it.

Now let's find `k`. Similar considerations, as with the differential equation solving apply:

```
ksol = Solve[p1[20] == 50, k, Reals]
(* {{k -> 1/20 (-Log[2] - 2 Log[5] + Log[1013])}} *)
ksol = First[ksol]
(* {k -> 1/20 (-Log[2] - 2 Log[5] + Log[1013])} *)
```

Now `ksol` is a rule that says "replace `k` with this number of `1/20(-Log[2]...`. We can now find a numeric value for, say p1[20].

```
p1[20] /. ksol
(* 50 *)
```

Which, unsurprisingly, is `50`. Again, we're saying to Mathematica "give me the value of `p1[20]`, but bear in mind that rule `ksol` applies (`/. ksol`), which tells you to replace all occurences of `k` with a specific number. This can be plotted.

```
Plot[p1[h] /. ksol, {h, 0, 25}]
```

As before, the rule should be applied, otherwise we won't get a numeric `y`-value to plot.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this in details. I am sure its already somewhere on this site but...

Comment: Not a problem. M.se is my way of procrastinating :-)

Comment: be careful, it is very very efficient!

Comment: @LLlAMnYP thank you sir, hell of an answer #__#. Thanks a lot. Now i understood it all :-)

Comment: Now what kind of slot/pattern object could `#__#` possibly be?

Comment: Ghosh my answer has been de-accepted! Didn't know it was technically possible. Oh well….

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the ODE:

```
DE = p'[h] == -k p[h];
```

Let us solve for the function `h`

```
sol = First[DSolve[{DE, p[0] == 1013}, p, h]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `sol` is a rule defining the function `p`;

Then applying the corresponding rule, we can solve for k:

```
rule2= First[Solve[ReplaceAll[p[20], sol] == 50 , k, Reals]];
ReplaceAll[ k, rule2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can define a new function with the correct value of `k`

```
p1[h_] = p[h] /. sol
```

(* 1013 E^(-h k) *)

And Plot it:

```
Plot[p1[h]/. rule2, {h, 0, 80}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank u chris. Can you tell me one other thing. After solving for k. I want to plot p[h] so i used, Plot[p[h],{h,0,80}]. But this does not seem to work. Can u help please.

Comment: Your "replaceall" is having me spinning, i was not able to understand, can u write in  a way that a newbie can understand, without using so many keywords. thanks

Comment: thanks for your effort :-). But i still dont know how to plot it.